# Receiving a Compile error - For Without Next

Tags: vba, excel

I have a built out an estimating system that we can take onsite when we deliver a quote to a client and the sheet I am working on is where all of the data I collect onsite compiles and is styled to deliver to our clients. I have multiple estimators working this template so automation is key. I have created a HURows() macro that worked for another one of my sheets but this time I am receiving a Compile Error stating "For Without Next".

```
Sub HURows()
    BeginRow = 192
    EndRow = 277
    ChkCol = 22

    For RowCnt = 192 To 196
        If Cells(193, 22).Value = 0 Then
            Cells(192, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Cells(193, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Cells(194, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Cells(195, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Cells(196, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Cells(242, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Cells(243, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Cells(244, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Cells(245, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            Cells(192, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Cells(193, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Cells(194, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Cells(195, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Cells(196, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Cells(242, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Cells(243, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Cells(244, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Cells(245, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
        If Cells(194, 22).Value = 0 Then
            Cells(194, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Cells(195, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Cells(243, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Cells(244, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            Cells(194, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Cells(195, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Cells(243, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Cells(244, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
        If Cells(195, 22).Value = 0 Then
            Cells(195, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Cells(245, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            Cells(195, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Cells(245, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
        If Cells(198, 22).Value = 0 Then
            Cells(197, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Cells(198, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Cells(199, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Cells(246, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Cells(247, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            Cells(197, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Cells(198, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Cells(199, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Cells(246, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Cells(247, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
        If Cells(201, 22).Value = 0 Then
            Cells(200, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Cells(201, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Cells(202, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Cells(203, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Cells(204, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Cells(248, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Cells(249, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Cells(250, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Cells(251, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            Cells(200, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Cells(201, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Cells(202, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Cells(203, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Cells(204, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Cells(248, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Cells(249, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Cells(250, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Cells(251, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
        If Cells(202, 22).Value = 0 Then
            Cells(202, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Cells(250, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            Cells(200, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Cells(202, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Cells(248, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Cells(250, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Cells(204, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
        If Cells(203, 22).Value = 0 Then
            Cells(203, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Cells(251, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            Cells(200, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Cells(203, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Cells(248, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Cells(251, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Cells(204, 22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: In general, it is agreed here that [you shouldn't use greetings or salutations in your posts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276033/pointless-question-edit/276037#276037). They get in the way of us readers figuring out the actual question. I've edited them out for you this time.

Comment: Read the **words** in the error message. They tell you *precisely* what the problem is you're having.

Comment: This is not even a mismatched `If`, you are literally just missing a `Next`  -  Alex K's allover this.

Answer (score 2):

You have used For without next.

The structure of for-next is like-

```
For i= 1 to 100

......do something....

Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Review this [link](http://www.databison.com/vba-for-loop-for-next-and-for-each-in-next/).  You are missing `Next` after your last `End If`.

***[Google is my friend.](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/134479?hl=en)***